# Android: Proximity Alert

Tags: android, geolocation, proximity

I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-proximity-alerts-tutorial.html) about how to use the proximity alert and how to register it.
It all works but when I close the app (with the back button, not the home-button) then the proximity alert does not work anymore. Does anyone know how to set it so that it runs in the background?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you can not get location updates when your application is not running. Receiving location updates in the background is not a good idea since it drains battery power and the user might not be aware that the location is being tracked since the normal behavior for pressing the back button on the application is for it to close all services. If I want my application to continue running in the background, I as a user would press the home button.

Look at the model used by the "My Tracks" application. 
Also see the documentation from Android on locations and usage models:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

If you have informed yourself about the reasons not to have the application do this in the background but still want to run this in the background, look into Services 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html 
They can run in the background and provide your application with data when asked.

Comment: I doubt this. The addProximityAlert method says nothing about no longer working if the Activity is not in the foreground. In my testing, the GPS icon is ON even though my activity is no longer in the foreground.

Comment: @SvenHaiges you may be right about that. Looking into the documentation also says that it should work.

Comment: Thx. either way I think using the proximity alerts is a bad idea. I did some tests - even though the alerts did not fire for me, the GPS was on all the time. I somewhere read that it would use both network and GPS - whatever is beset suited (e.g. far away from next lat/long, it would use wifi)... but I am not sure if that is well implemented. I'll probably write a service that checks in the background. Then I can also decide myself when to turn the location checks on and off...

Comment: @SvenHaiges for sure i will do the same: my own solution/service. AddProximityAlert does suck., and the documentatin, as usual, very very poor

Answer (score 1):

Fundamental part of Android... Services.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

Answer (score 0):

You should get it if you register for it, but keep in mind that proximity alert may not be immediate if your screen is off. If your screen is off, then location is probed for every 4 minutes as stated in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert%28double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29).

Comment: "location is probed for every 4 minutes" really? Where did you read it @fatih ?

Comment: My answer based on the documentation that I read back in 2012. It's highly probable that they improved their proximity alert functionality considerably to make it more intelligent. I've published couple research papers on this issue. https://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~demirbas/publications/proximity.pdf